# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Set the SECRET_KEY environment variable what you said in the previous question doesn't work

Tags: python, django, environment-variables, secret-key, environ

I can not run the project, I did what I was told in README.md as directed, but still gives an error.

## The Output is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\environ\environ.py", line 403, in get_value
    value = self.ENVIRON[var_name]
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen os>", line 678, in __getitem__
KeyError: 'SECRET_KEY'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\new-folder\manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\new-folder\manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 402, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 448, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 93, in wrapped
    saved_locale = translation.get_language()
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\utils\translation\__init__.py", line 210, in get_language
    return _trans.get_language()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\utils\translation\__init__.py", line 65, in __getattr__
    if settings.USE_I18N:
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 92, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 79, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 190, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\new-folder\usn_uchet\settings.py", line 26, in <module>
    SECRET_KEY = ENV.str('SECRET_KEY')
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\environ\environ.py", line 213, in str
    value = self.get_value(var, cast=str, default=default)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\environ\environ.py", line 407, in get_value
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg) from exc
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Set the SECRET_KEY environment variable
```

## settings.py file

```
import os
import environ
from pathlib import Path
from django.utils.log import DEFAULT_LOGGING
import urllib3

import sentry_sdk
from sentry_sdk.integrations.django import DjangoIntegration


BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

ENV = environ.Env(DEBUG=(bool, True))


ENV_FILE = Path(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '.env'))
if ENV_FILE.exists():
    environ.Env.read_env(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '.env'))

DEBUG = ENV.bool('DEBUG', True)
LOGLEVEL = ENV.str('LOGLEVEL', 'INFO')
SECRET_KEY = ENV.str('SECRET_KEY')
CRYPTO_KEY = bytes(ENV.str('CRYPTO_KEY'), 'UTF-8')
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ENV.list('ALLOWED_HOSTS', default=[])
```

## .env file

```
DEBUG=on
SECRET_KEY=My_key
```

and how do I fix this error to start the server ?
what to do to get rid of this error tried to remove the space, also added to the directory where the settings.py.what you said in the previous question doesn't work

Comment: Where did you load env file on your system?
Try that for start :
`SECRET_KEY = ENV.str('SECRET_KEY','My_key')`

Comment: fixed the SECRET_KEY error, now I have a new error django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Set the CRYPTO_KEY environment variable

Comment: .env should be kept at the root directory, it worked for me